# How to set the bitmap size to show it proper on SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, bitmap

I am using SurfaceView to draw the Bitmap Image. But the Problem is while i am setting the image on the SurfaceView, it will not seen whole image.

I think it happend because the imahe size is larger then the device screen size.

So i want to set the bitmap that should be set with the device size/ SurfaceView Size.

If the Image is smaller then the SurfaceView then it should be in image size and at center of the surfaceView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Filepath);
final int REQUIRED_SIZE=100;//what ever your surface size or require size

int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
int scale=1;

while(true){
if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
break;
width_tmp/=2;
height_tmp/=2;
scale*=2;

}

BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.inSampleSize = scale;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, op);

use this bitmap.
```

Comment: SurfaceSize means ? I mean it should be measure in height and width and u have measure it in just single variable name as REQUIRED_SIZE.

Comment: i mean the size of screen or the image size which u require. which size u require set it in REQUIRED_SIZE variable.

Comment: Yes i can understand but Size should be measure in height and width. Then how you get the size in just One Variable ????

Comment: both will be same. if you set 100 then width and height both will be 100